# Store an event which is associate with element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have requirement to remove some element and get it back when required. I have red about the `.detach()` which do almost I required but the things is I have to done it with javascript.

```
<div id="get">a</div>

document.getElementById("get").addEventListener('click',function(){
alert(0)
})
```

Comment: Maybe you can use removeEventListener

Comment: No, I want store it with its attached event. so that I can retrieve  it again

Comment: @Teemu I think he wants the functionality of `$.fn.detach` without jquery

Comment: @AmitJoki You're probably right, the event listener in the code causes a bit confusion. amit, you can do `removed = parent.removeChild()` method, but you must keep a reference to `removed` alive, so that you can use it when you need to re-attach the removed element. A simple way would be to set `display: none` for the element to "remove" though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep the binding on the node as maybe you are appending it later on why not store the node with its event bindings?

http://jsfiddle.net/w4699vm8/

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("get"),
    wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

myDiv.addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert(0);
});

wrapper.removeChild(myDiv);

wrapper.appendChild(myDiv); //myDiv still has listener
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the same what I am looking for